# How can I copy one column and replace a column in another file (in R)

Tags: r

I have two .csv files as data frames in R and I'd like to figure out the commands to take the first column in one file and replace the same named column in another file.

Example of files:

```
(file1)
names,length,width
1,8.5,6.7
2,6.3,4.2
3,10.4,8.6
.
.
.
n,n,n

(file2)
names,length,width,height
spider,8.5,6.7,21.2
snake,6.3,4.2,34.5
frog,10.4,8.6,18.7
.
.
.
n,n,n,n
```

So, I want to take the "names" (column 1) in file2 and replace the column 1 of file1 (which are numbers - an unfortunate output from another function in R) with those actual names from "names" in file2.

It's probably very easy...but I just can't seem to get R to do what I want it to.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

*update - I got a great answer (below), but this takes the "names" column and tacks it onto the last column of the csv, leaving column1 as the numbers (1,2,3,...).
Any way of then taking that last column and moving it to column1 and overwriting that column?

Thanks!

Comment: `df1$names <- df2$names`

Comment: @JakeBurkhead's answer works if the data is of same length and same order, and I guess that is what you have. But why blame R with "an unfortunate output from another function in R", I guess you can control it over there, so you do not need post processing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  Yes, this works.  And yes, it's not necessarily the program's fault, it's a great program...I just couldn't find anything about how to control that from the manual.

Comment: I edited my original post above, but didn't know if you'd see it. - *update - I got a great answer (below), but this takes the "names" column and tacks it onto the last column of the csv, leaving column1 as the numbers (1,2,3,...). Any way of then taking that last column and moving it to column1 and overwriting that column?